# Error: Cannot find module './index.ts' when doing npm start with a package import

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-install, package.json

I'm new to working on OpenSource Projects and I'm currently exploring the area. I found this repository and I'm trying to solve an issue on it:
https://github.com/WJSoftware/wj-config/tree/Version_2

The issues need to be worked on the Version_2 branch. Because of that I cannot use npm install to install the package as a node module as it would install wj-config@2.0.0-beta.2.

When I download the package and place it inside the folder and followed the readme, I get the following error:

```
> tsest@1.0.0 start
> ts-node ./node_modules/wj-config/src/index.ts && ts-node ./node_modules/wj-config/src/Builder.ts index.js

node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:988
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module './index.ts'
Require stack:
- /Users/neeraj_py/Desktop/Repositories/wj-config/test_module/node_modules/wj-config/src/imaginaryUncacheableRequireResolveScript
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:985:15)
    at Function.resolve (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:109:19)
    at requireResolveNonCached (/Users/neeraj_py/Desktop/Repositories/wj-config/test_module/node_modules/ts-node/dist/bin.js:549:16)
    at getProjectSearchDir (/Users/neeraj_py/Desktop/Repositories/wj-config/test_module/node_modules/ts-node/dist/bin.js:519:40)
    at phase3 (/Users/neeraj_py/Desktop/Repositories/wj-config/test_module/node_modules/ts-node/dist/bin.js:267:27)
    at bootstrap (/Users/neeraj_py/Desktop/Repositories/wj-config/test_module/node_modules/ts-node/dist/bin.js:47:30)
    at main (/Users/neeraj_py/Desktop/Repositories/wj-config/test_module/node_modules/ts-node/dist/bin.js:33:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/neeraj_py/Desktop/Repositories/wj-config/test_module/node_modules/ts-node/dist/bin.js:579:5)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1149:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1203:10) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/Users/neeraj_py/Desktop/Repositories/wj-config/test_module/node_modules/wj-config/src/imaginaryUncacheableRequireResolveScript'
  ]
}

Node.js v18.10.0
```

These are my files:

config.js

```
import wjConfig, { Environment } from './wj-config/src/index.ts';
import mainConfig from "./config/config.json" assert {type: 'json'}; // Importing data is a thing in NodeJS.
import fs from 'fs';

// If importing JSON was not a thing in NodecJS, mainConfig would be the result of calling this function.
const loadJsonFile = (fileName, isRequired) => {
    const fileExists = fs.existsSync(fileName);
    if (fileExists) {
        const data = fs.readFileSync(fileName);
        return JSON.parse(data);
    }
    else if (isRequired) {
        throw new Error(`Configuration file ${fileName} is required but was not found.`);
    }
    // Return an empty object.
    return {};
};

// Obtain an environment object ahead of time to help setting up configuration.
const env = new Environment(process.env.NODE_ENV);

const config = wjConfig()
    .addObject(mainConfig)
    .name('Main Configuration') // Give data sources a meaningful name for value tracing purposes.
    .addObject(loadJsonFile(`./config/config.Development.json`))
    .name(`${env.value} Configuration`)
    .addEnvironment(process.env) // Adds a data source that reads the environment variables in process.env.
    .includeEnvironment(env) // So the final configuration object has the environment property.
    .createUrlFunctions() // So the final configuration object will contain URL builder functions.
    .build(env.isDevelopment()); // Only trace configuration values in the Development environment.

export default await config; // The build() function is asynchronous, so await the result.
```

index.js

```
import config  from "./config.js";
console.log(config);
```

The repository uses ts files. Will I have to handle their compilation myself? Also I'm new to using ES Modules and node so I might have problems in some of my imports. Can anyone please suggest a way for me to create a sample node module to test out the package? The system I'm using runs macOS Monterey (Version 12.5.1) with M1

**Edit**: I tried using github branches as package dependency but it gives the error:

```
npm ERR! Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'spec')

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/neeraj_py/.npm/_logs/2022-11-04T04_08_06_849Z-debug-0.log
```

**/Users/neeraj_py/.npm/_logs/2022-11-04T04_08_06_849Z-debug-0.log**

```
0 verbose cli /opt/homebrew/Cellar/node/18.10.0/bin/node /opt/homebrew/bin/npm
1 info using npm@8.19.2
2 info using node@v18.10.0
3 timing npm:load:whichnode Completed in 0ms
4 timing config:load:defaults Completed in 1ms
5 timing config:load:file:/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/npm/npmrc Completed in 1ms
6 timing config:load:builtin Completed in 2ms
7 timing config:load:cli Completed in 1ms
8 timing config:load:env Completed in 0ms
9 timing config:load:file:/Users/neeraj_py/Desktop/Repositories/wj-config/test_module/.npmrc Completed in 0ms
10 timing config:load:project Completed in 2ms
11 timing config:load:file:/Users/neeraj_py/.npmrc Completed in 0ms
12 timing config:load:user Completed in 0ms
13 timing config:load:file:/opt/homebrew/etc/npmrc Completed in 0ms
14 timing config:load:global Completed in 0ms
15 timing config:load:validate Completed in 0ms
16 timing config:load:credentials Completed in 1ms
17 timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 0ms
18 timing config:load Completed in 7ms
19 timing npm:load:configload Completed in 7ms
20 timing npm:load:mkdirpcache Completed in 1ms
21 timing npm:load:mkdirplogs Completed in 0ms
22 verbose title npm install WJSoftware/wj-config#Version_2
23 verbose argv "install" "--save" "WJSoftware/wj-config#Version_2" "-or-commit-or-tag"
24 timing npm:load:setTitle Completed in 2ms
25 timing config:load:flatten Completed in 1ms
26 timing npm:load:display Completed in 2ms
27 verbose logfile logs-max:10 dir:/Users/neeraj_py/.npm/_logs
28 verbose logfile /Users/neeraj_py/.npm/_logs/2022-11-04T04_08_06_849Z-debug-0.log
29 timing npm:load:logFile Completed in 2ms
30 timing npm:load:timers Completed in 0ms
31 timing npm:load:configScope Completed in 0ms
32 timing npm:load Completed in 14ms
33 timing arborist:ctor Completed in 0ms
34 silly logfile start cleaning logs, removing 1 files
35 silly logfile done cleaning log files
36 timing idealTree:init Completed in 19ms
37 timing arborist:ctor Completed in 0ms
38 timing idealTree:userRequests Completed in 2584ms
39 silly idealTree buildDeps
40 silly fetch manifest undefined@WJSoftware/wj-config#Version_2
41 silly placeDep ROOT undefined@ OK for: tsest@1.0.0 want: WJSoftware/wj-config#Version_2
42 timing idealTree:#root Completed in 1560ms
43 timing idealTree:node_modules/undefined Completed in 0ms
44 timing idealTree:buildDeps Completed in 1560ms
45 timing idealTree:fixDepFlags Completed in 0ms
46 timing idealTree Completed in 4165ms
47 timing reify:loadTrees Completed in 4165ms
48 timing reify:diffTrees Completed in 1ms
49 silly reify moves {}
50 timing reify:retireShallow Completed in 1ms
51 timing reify:createSparse Completed in 0ms
52 timing reify:loadBundles Completed in 0ms
53 silly audit bulk request {
53 silly audit   '@cspotcode/source-map-support': [ '0.8.1' ],
53 silly audit   '@jridgewell/resolve-uri': [ '3.1.0' ],
53 silly audit   '@jridgewell/sourcemap-codec': [ '1.4.14' ],
53 silly audit   '@jridgewell/trace-mapping': [ '0.3.9' ],
53 silly audit   '@tsconfig/node10': [ '1.0.9' ],
53 silly audit   '@tsconfig/node12': [ '1.0.11' ],
53 silly audit   '@tsconfig/node14': [ '1.0.3' ],
53 silly audit   '@tsconfig/node16': [ '1.0.3' ],
53 silly audit   '@types/node': [ '18.11.0' ],
53 silly audit   acorn: [ '8.8.0' ],
53 silly audit   'acorn-walk': [ '8.2.0' ],
53 silly audit   arg: [ '4.1.3' ],
53 silly audit   'create-require': [ '1.1.1' ],
53 silly audit   diff: [ '4.0.2' ],
53 silly audit   'make-error': [ '1.3.6' ],
53 silly audit   'ts-node': [ '10.9.1' ],
53 silly audit   typescript: [ '4.8.4' ],
53 silly audit   'v8-compile-cache-lib': [ '3.0.1' ],
53 silly audit   yn: [ '3.1.1' ]
53 silly audit }
54 http fetch POST 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/-/npm/v1/security/advisories/bulk 565ms
55 timing auditReport:getReport Completed in 568ms
56 silly audit report {}
57 timing auditReport:init Completed in 1ms
58 timing reify:audit Completed in 570ms
59 http fetch GET 200 https://codeload.github.com/WJSoftware/wj-config/tar.gz/11e176968b2ccf8dfaca6c23d8a98a24fb2e3678 607ms (cache revalidated)
60 timing reifyNode:node_modules/undefined Completed in 893ms
61 timing reify:unpack Completed in 893ms
62 timing reify:unretire Completed in 0ms
63 timing build:queue Completed in 1ms
64 timing build:deps Completed in 1ms
65 timing build Completed in 1ms
66 timing reify:build Completed in 1ms
67 timing reify:trash Completed in 0ms
68 timing command:install Completed in 5067ms
69 verbose stack TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'spec')
69 verbose stack     at updateNodes (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/reify.js:1179:44)
69 verbose stack     at [saveIdealTree] (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/reify.js:1348:11)
69 verbose stack     at Arborist.reify (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/reify.js:156:31)
69 verbose stack     at async Install.exec (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/commands/install.js:145:5)
69 verbose stack     at async module.exports (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cli.js:78:5)
70 verbose cwd /Users/neeraj_py/Desktop/Repositories/wj-config/test_module
71 verbose Darwin 21.6.0
72 verbose node v18.10.0
73 verbose npm  v8.19.2
74 error Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'spec')
75 verbose exit 1
76 timing npm Completed in 5125ms
77 verbose unfinished npm timer reify 1667534886907
78 verbose unfinished npm timer reify:save 1667534891972
79 verbose code 1
80 error A complete log of this run can be found in:
80 error     /Users/neeraj_py/.npm/_logs/2022-11-04T04_08_06_849Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: you can use github branch as package dependecy: https://medium.com/@jonchurch/use-github-branch-as-dependency-in-package-json-5eb609c81f1a

and I wonder if it is possible to import typescript file into javascript file.

Comment: @SonuBamniya I tried that but it's showing this error: npm ERR! Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'spec')

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/neeraj_py/.npm/_logs/2022-11-04T04_08_06_849Z-debug-0.log